# Definition of functor

Tags: category-theory, functors

This is a question addressed to those familiar with category theory, since it concerns the preferability of two similar definitions, which I suppose is revealed only by further experience. In sum, the question is whether or not to mean functor as a property of couples of functions or as to couple of functions with built-in domain and codomain (which are categories). I point out that I myself include domains and codomains in the definition of (set-theoretic) functions.

The two definitions of functor are the following:

1. according to the first one, a functor can be defined as a(n ordered) quadruplet in which the first two components are categories, called respectively domain and codomain of the functor, and the others are functions (possibly class functions) between the objects and the morphisms of the latter categories, satisfying appropriate conditions;
2. according to the other, one says that a couple of functions is a functor from category $C$ to category $D$ if the first (second) one maps objects (morphisms) of $C$ to objects (morphisms) of $D$ satisfying the same conditions as case (1).

The two definitions are distinct, since in the second case a functor is a particular couple of function (so 'to be a functor from $C$ to $D$' is precisely a property of couples of functions), whereas it is not that case in definition 1.

As an other example, definition (2) allows a couple of functions to be a functor for multiple categories in ways (1) does not: e.g., a (2)-functor from $C$ to $D$ is also a (2)-functor from $C^\text{op}$ to $D^\text{op}$, whereas according to (1) it generally isn't (clearly enough, unless $C^\text{op} = C$ and $D^\text{op} = D$).

Comment: I feel allowed to give my 2 cents because this is not "higher level" category theory. It is the B.A.BA. Don't bother and waste so much time on this, the two definitions are identical because in the second one, you (rightly) specified first "is a functor *from category C to category D*". So, it *cannot* be also "a functor from Cop to Dop (clearly unless C = Cop and D = Dop)".

Comment: I agree this is not "higher level", neither did I say that: a further knowledge is anyway required to answer an elementary doubt in a non-dogmatic way. According to the second definition, I can say of the same couple of functions to be both a functor from C to D and a functor from Cop to Dop: the same object has these two different properties. In the first definition, there cannot be (in general) such an object.

Comment: FYI, "higher" is used in a specific way in category theory -- [Higher category theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher_category_theory) -- so probably another adjective (perhaps "at a more advanced level"?) would be more appropriate.

Comment: I thank you for this information which I knew about. The expression "at a higher level" does not seem to me quite inherent to that branch. I'll edit the question to prevent further delays.

Comment: This smells like the difference between constructing $\Bbb Z$ from $\Bbb N$ and from constructing $\Bbb Z$ from $\Bbb R$. Either way, you get "the" integers and we write it all as $\Bbb Z$ because the difference almost never matters. In your case, either way you get a notion of functor which captures the same ideas and does the same things. playing fast and loose with the size issues you could even establish an isomorphism between functors-of-type-$(1)$ from $C\to D$ and functors-of-type-$(2)$

Comment: In your last sentence, you refer to definition (2) and contrast that with the second definition. Could you fix up that last paragraph for clarity?

Comment: I've rephrased the whole paragraph. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: @FShrike [Refurbishing the previous comment due to a mistake] I have myself spent much time investigating (some of) the various ways of treating number systems and at some levels I find them rather non-equivalent, in that each of them sheds light and exploits peculiar aspects of them. Due to my lack of experience in category theory, I can't see the analogy with my question, but if that is the case, a fortiori I think it should be addressed properly. I thank you for recalling that correspondence, but I would find a comparative enquiry (with examples of pro's and con's) more satisfactory.

Comment: Even if you use definition (2) and look at pair of (possibly class) functions, they have their domain and codomain which are objects and morphisms of corresponding categories. How would you have two different categories with same objects and morphisms?

Comment: @Ennar -- $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{C}^\text{op}$ have the same objects and the same arrows. They differ only in the choice of source/target/composition maps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer you probably don't want is that these kinds of "implementation details" really don't matter at all. Pick whichever makes you happiest, and it will never impact the answers to category-theoretic questions.

---

First, let me give a simpler example to make sure that I understand what you're asking:

We have "two possible implementations" for a group homomorphism $(G, \cdot) \to (H, \star)$.

1. A triple $((G,\cdot),(H,\star),f)$ where $f : G \to H$ is a map on underlying sets (satisfying certain conditions)
2. A function $f : G \to H$ on the underlying sets (satisfying certain conditions)

Now you worry that, under definition $2$, two different homomorphisms can have *the same implementation*. For instance, if we define $\cdot^\text{op} : G \times G \to G$ as $a \cdot^\text{op} b = b \cdot a$, then the same function $f$ can represent both a homomorphism $(G, \cdot) \to (H, \star)$ *and* to $(G,\cdot^\text{op}) \to (H,\star^\text{op})$ because these two homomorphisms have the same underlying function!

In definition $1$, we explicitly "tag" our function with its domain and codomain as *groups* so that the two homomorphisms $((G,\cdot), \ (H,\star), \ f)$ and $((G,\cdot^\text{op}), \ (H, \star^\text{op}), \ f)$ are encoded by different objects in the ambient set theory.

If I understand correctly, you're asking basically the same question, but in the context of categories and functors rather than groups and homomorphisms.

---

Now, in the group theoretic case and the category theoretic case, *these implementation details don't matter*. You will never be presented with a naked function out in the wild (or pair of functions in the category case) and asked "what is the group structure on the domain of this function?". Ironically, given the question, we can make this precise using category theory! Whenever we interact with a homomorphism $f$, we're really interacting with $f \in \text{Hom}((G,\cdot), (H,\star))$! We always have the bonus context on hand of what the domain and codomain should be. So, if you want${}^1$, you can absolutely use definition $1$ and tag your homomorphisms (functors) with the group structure (category structure) on their source and target.

Why does category theory make this precise? Because we can define categories of groups $\mathsf{Grp}_1$ and $\mathsf{Grp}_2$ using the two implementations of homsets. It's an easy exercise to show that these categories are equivalent (in fact, isomorphic!) so that, in this precise sense, you cannot distinguish the two definitions using only group theoretic questions. Similarly, you can build two categories $\mathsf{Cat}_1$ and $\mathsf{Cat}_2$ using the two definitions of functor, and you can show that *these* categories are also isomorphic${}^2$! So the answer to any "category theoretic question" you can ask won't depend on whether you choose definition 1 or 2!

---

I hope this helps ^_^

---

${}^1$: and it seems like you *do* want this, since you say you're doing this for your arrows in $\mathsf{Set}$

${}^2$: you do have to eat your tail a *little bit* since checking isomorphism of categories requires working in a category of categories. And in this category of categories you need a notion of functor, so you have to choose a definition before you can prove the two definitions agree... But this is really no different than any other time we have two equivalent definitions and we have to choose one "official" one to write down first.